# How to set default decimal value to input in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind input value 0.00 to text box 
then, if I changed input to 20 then on blur set 20.00

```
<input type="text" valid-decimal-number style="text-align:right"  ng-model="Amount"  ng-blur="ConvertToDecimal(Amount)">
```

**angular script :**

```
//converting value to decimal
$scope.ConvertToDecimal = function (val) {
   $scope.Amount = eval(val).toFixed(2);
}
```

I am getting by using this code but, for  every time I'm writing,
how to create custom directive for this

I tried like this also but not working.

```
<input type="text" valid-decimal-number style="text-align:right"  ng-model="Amount"  ng-blur="'Amount=(Amount).toFixed(2)'">
```

Comment: Remove ' from ng-blur

Comment: i have tried removing that also, text box becoming empty after blur event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a filter in `ng-blur`

```
ng-blur="Amount = (Amount | number : 2 )"
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="text" style="text-align:right"  ng-model="Amount" ng-blur="Amount = (Amount | number : 2 )" >

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sachila , its worked.Is it possible to create custom directive for this

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `toFixed(2)` to numbers only

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" valid-decimal-number style="text-align:right"  ng-model="Amount"  ng-blur="ConvertToDecimal()">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.ConvertToDecimal = function (val) {
 if(isNaN($scope.Amount)){
  alert("given input is not a number");
  return;
 }
        $scope.Amount = Number($scope.Amount).toFixed(2);
    }
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```